# Elastic Search : Expected numeric type on field

Tags: elasticsearch

All the fields that i need to calculate the SUM are INT but when i make the request i got this error :

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Expected numeric type on field [mlf16_txservnum], but got [string]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "bpa_stag_v3",
                "node": "zzsbvdwmQ0-d0Ca_b3w0uQ",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                    "reason": "Expected numeric type on field [mlf16_txservnum], but got [string]"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Here the request :

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : [ {
        "term" : {
          "mlf16_cptfou_six" : "095436"
        }
      }, {
        "term" : {
          "mlf16_codadres" : "00"
        }
      }, {
        "term" : {
          "mlf16_semind" : "24"
        }
      }, {
        "term" : {
          "mlf16_annee" : "2017"
        }
      } ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "Sum_Service_Rate_Numerator" : {
      "sum" : {
        "field" : "mlf16_txservnum"
      }
    },
    "Sum_Service_Rate_Denominator" : {
      "sum" : {
        "field" : "mlf16_txservden"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here the index without any aggregation :

```
{
                "_index": "bpa_stag_v3",
                "_type": "indic_semaine_yassine",
                "_id": "2017-06-11,2017,23,23,0000900156,05,0000241235,00,00,5I,3,0,19,0,2,0,0,3,2,2,0,12,3,241235,2017",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "dt_extract": "2017-06-11",
                    "mlf16_annee": "2017",
                    "mlf16_semind": "23",
                    "mlf16_semcal": "23",
                    "mlf16_cptmag": "0000900156",
                    "mlf16_codraft": "05",
                    "mlf16_cptfou": "0000241235",
                    "mlf16_codadrdl": "00",
                    "mlf16_codadres": "00",
                    "mlf16_grpges": "5I",
                    "mlf16_clasges": "3",
                    "mlf16_txservnum": 0,
                    "mlf16_txservden": 19,
                    "mlf16_txdocnum": 0,
                    "mlf16_txdocden": 2,
                    "mlf16_txfiabnum": 0,
                    "mlf16_txfiabden": 0,
                    "mlf16_refret2j": 3,
                    "mlf16_refret7j": 2,
                    "mlf16_refret21j": 2,
                    "mlf16_natcouv": "0",
                    "mlf16_nbligndiff": 12,
                    "mlf16_nbrefdiff": 3,
                    "mlf16_cptfou_six": "241235",
                    "dt_year": 2017,
                    "es_id": "2017-06-11,2017,23,23,0000900156,05,0000241235,00,00,5I,3,0,19,0,2,0,0,3,2,2,0,12,3,241235,2017"
                }
            },
```

Here the mapping of my index :

```
{
    "bpa_stag_v3": {
        "mappings": {
            "indic_semaine_yassine": {
                "dynamic_templates": [
                    {
                        "string_fields": {
                            "mapping": {
                                "index": "not_analyzed",
                                "omit_norms": true,
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "match": "*",
                            "match_mapping_type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "dt_extract": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                    },
                    "dt_year": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "es_id": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_annee": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_clasges": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_codadrdl": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_codadres": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_codraft": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_cptfou": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_cptfou_six": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_cptmag": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_grpges": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_natcouv": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_nbligndiff": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_nbrefdiff": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                    },
                    "mlf16_refret21j": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_refret2j": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_refret7j": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_semcal": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_semind": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_txdocden": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_txdocnum": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_txfiabden": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_txfiabnum": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_txservden": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "mlf16_txservnum": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the mapping of your index. `GET index/type/_mapping`. Seems it is of type `string`

Comment: @Richa ok . you can check it know . Thanks

Comment: I think `mapping` query did not run successfully. It does not take any body. Just run `GET index_name/type_name/_mapping`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your exception says, `"reason": "Expected numeric type on field [mlf16_txservnum], but got [string]"`, it clearly says that `mlf16_txservnum` is string but numeric expected because aggregation `sum` can be only applied to numbers, not string and in your mapping, you have specified datatype of `mlf16_txservnum` to string.

```
"mlf16_txservnum": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
}
```

Change the type in your mapping to number (integer, double etc.) for this field and **other fields** that you performing sum:

```
"mlf16_txservnum": {
    "type": "integer"
}
```

Comment: how can i change it ?

Comment: `"index": "not_analyzed" ` is not necessary on `integer` fields

Comment: In my DB , the field is an integer not a string but when we load the data in ES . it take automatically the type String

Comment: @YasBES you need to manually set mapping for you index. check for documentation here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

Comment: @RaKa but why in Json Document , the fields are not a string "mlf16_txservnum": 0, "mlf16_txservden": 19

Comment: @YasBES I won't be able to tell why its displaying as such, may be some invalid configuration or so, but you can assure the type of these fields are correct or not by checking the mapping configuraiton - simple get - /yourindex to view mapping config and confirm field type.

Answer (score 3):

I think @RA KA explained the issue and fix.But there is another way to fix as well. If your data is huge and can't reindex, You can change the data type of value on run time.

```
"aggregations" : {
 "Sum_Service_Rate_Numerator" : {
  "sum" : {
    "field" : 'Integer.parseInt(doc["mlf16_txservnum"].value)'
  }
},
"Sum_Service_Rate_Denominator" : {
  "sum" : {
    "field" : 'Integer.parseInt(doc["mlf16_txservden"].value)'
  }
 }
}
```

Hope this Helps..!

Comment: However, while using the Java API, when the response is being parsed into a SearchResponse object, this will throw the following exception: exception ParsingException[Could not parse aggregation keyed as [Sum_Service_Rate_Numerator]]